# How to call my fabfile within my Python script

Tags: python, ssh, boto, fabric

I am struggling to launch my fabfile within my Python script. I have looked at similar posts on Stack Overflow regarding this but they don't solve my problem... Or maybe they do but I am not understanding them...Not sure.

My script writes to the fab file depending on what the user wants to run on the remote host. Here is an example of the fabfile:

```
[root@ip-50-50-50-50 bakery]# cat fabfile.py
from fabric.api import run
def deploy():
    run('wget -P /tmp https://s3.amazonaws.com/MyBucket/httpd-2.2.26-1.1.amzn1.x86_64.rpm')
    run('sudo yum localinstall /tmp/httpd-2.2.26-1.1.amzn1.x86_64.rpm')
```

I then need to run the fabfile from my script. If I run the following manually form the Command Line, then it works fine:

```
fab -f fabfile.py -u ec2-user -i id_rsa -H 10.10.15.150 deploy
```

1) How do I run that from inside my script with all of the options? 
2) The IP address is a variable called "bakery_internalip". How do I call that variable as part of the fab line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with subprocess :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['fab', '-f', 'fabfile.py', '-u ec2-user', '-i', 'id_rsa', '-H', bakery_internalip, 'deploy'])
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks. That appears to work for the most part. The only trouble I am having now is that I am getting this error:

Fatal error: Fabfile didn't contain any commands!

I don't understand how that is as the fabfile definitely contains commands and works fine from the command line. the fabfile is also in the same directory from which the script is being run. I also tried to specify the full path to the script.

Comment: Sounds like maybe it's interpreting your Python script as a bash script and not finding any commands.  Do you have a shebang at the top?

Comment: The Python script definitely has a shebang and is being interpreted correctly. For some reason, it is saying that it cannot find any commands in my fabfile.py

Answer (score 0):

You can call fabric enabled commands directly from code. Usually you will have to set the env dictionary first to specify keys and host but is is very straightforward:

```
# the settings for the env dict
from fabric.api import env, execute
env.hosts = ["10.10.15.150", ]
env.user = "ec2-user"
env.key = "id_rsa"

# and call the function itself
from fabfile import deplot
execute(deploy, hosts=env.hosts)
```

You can find more inspiration in the fabric documentation:
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/usage/execution.html#using-execute-with-dynamically-set-host-lists